# Shared element transition between TextView and EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-transitions

I tried to share a text between `TextView` (source) and `EditText` (destination) but it didn't work properly.

The context of issue is "[Start an activity with a shared element](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions)" transition, using the `android:transtionName` attribute.

After new Activity is started, all others shared views (`ImageView`) have and display their values. The `EditText` knows the contents because when I set the focus it appears correctly. The logger of "`et.getText()`" show that `EditText` content it's ok but isn't displayed.

The sequence of operations is as follows:

1. Source Activity 'A' have the original data:

   - `TextView` value: "Hello world". `android:transtionName="transition_text"`
   - `TextView` display: "Hello world"
2. On user event, Activity 'B' is launched using shared element transition and adding all the elements that are to be shared.
3. Into 'B' `onCreate` method the shared data is get and set properly. All elements contains their value but EditText doesn't display it:

   - `EditText` value: "Hello world". `android:transtionName="transition_text"`
   - `EditText` display: ""

It's possible that shared element transition not allow transitions between different type text views (`TextView` -> `EditText`)?

Thanks

Comment: can you post some code.

Comment: I have the same problem. A transition from an `EditText` to a `TextView` works just fine, but not the other way around. After the `TextView` to `EditText` transition, the text will show up if I tap on the `EditText`, so I guess it's a problem with calculating the layout inside the `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to getText from **`TextView`** and then covert **`toString()`** and then setText on **`EditText`**

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
EditText et = new EditText(this);
tv.setText("Hello World");

String source = tv.getText().toString();
et.setText(source);
```

Comment: But why is `toString()` required? `getText()` returns `CharSequence` and `setText()` accepts `CharSequence`. How is it going to make any difference?

Comment: yes both are work but sometime i make a problem because i post this :)

Comment: The text is set into `EditText` properly, but doesn't show it when I using "shared element transition" between activities. I have improved the explanation to avoid confusion.

Comment: @JoseD.Jurado hey did you find any solution to that ? as i am also facing the same problem.